# Automatic properties and Nullable types - are they incompatible?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a custom type with a nullable property that I am trying to project into from a nullable column in SQL. I am always getting a 'missingmethodexception' like so:

```
{"Method not found: 'Void MyType.set_Number(System.Nullable`1<Int32>)'."}
```

Is there a problem with trying to project into a custom type with nullable automatic properties? The code looks like this:

```
public class MyType {        
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Value { get; set;}
    public int? Number { get; set;}
}

Dictionary<int, CustomType> dict;

dict = (from t in table
        select new {
           id = av.Account.Id,
           mt = new MyType { Name = t.Name, Value = t.Value, Number = t.Number }
        }).ToDictionary(item => item.id, item => item.mt);
```

Comment: t.Number is from the column in the table in the database and it is set to an 'int' type with allow nulls as true. I access the database through linq-to-sql.

Comment: I think the problem is in the setting of the 'Number' value though...

Comment: I guess you might have to do a translation here. Check if t.Number is a DBNull. Assign null if so else put the value.

Comment: See if this link helps - http://blogs.msdn.com/thottams/archive/2008/06/30/dbnull-and-nullable-types.aspx

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities? I just tried this code in L2S and it worked fine, converting `DBNull` to `null` with no problem.

Comment: I have similar code and at first its works well, but now I get same error, do you have an answer to the problem?

Comment: Could you share little bit more code? its too hard to repro exactly what you're hitting with the fragments you've given in the question.